# Yii2 пагинация на REST через offset, limit

Tags: yii2, rest

Подскажите каким образом можно осушествить выборку через  offset, limit. Клиент передает Start, и limit. Смотрю в сторону ActiveDataProvider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
public function actionIndex() {

    $query = Users::find();
    $queryCount = clone $query;
    $start = (int) \Yii::$app->request->get('start');
    $limit = (int) \Yii::$app->request->get('length');

    $users['data'] = $query->offset($start)
      ->limit($limit)
      ->all();

    $users['recordsTotal'] = $query->count();
    $users['recordsFiltered'] = $queryCount->count();

    return $users; 
}
```

Comment: Вы правы так лучше. Спасибо.

Comment: А вместо request->get можно сделать так actionIndex($start, $length)

Answer (score 0):

```
public function actionIndex() {

    $query = Users::find();
    $start = \Yii::$app->request->get('start');
    $limit = \Yii::$app->request->get('length');


    $pagination = new Pagination([
      'totalCount' => $query->count(),
    ]);

    $users['data'] = $query->offset($start)
      ->limit($limit)
      ->all();

    $users['recordsTotal'] = $pagination->totalCount;
    $users['recordsFiltered'] = $pagination->totalCount;

  return $users; 
  }
```

Покретикуйте

Comment: Показалось, что этот ответ - это часть вопроса. Добавил ваш же исправленный вариант ответом.

Comment: Не понимаю чем отличается recordsTotal от recordsFiltered и вообще не могу понять, какую роль выполняет Pagination. Мне кажется, достаточно offset и limit в запросе.

Comment: Это так сказать в поиске.